# Resizing a SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, resize, sprite-kit, skshapenode

How do I resize a SKShapeNode?

## What I've tried so far:

### Frame resize

`box.frame.width = 10`

Gives the error `Cannot assign to the result of this expression`

### SKAction

```
let actionResize = SKAction.resizeToWidth(10, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.1))
box.runAction(actionResize)
```

Nothing happens

### xScale

`box.xScale = 0.1`

Scales the node instead of resizing

Comment: how do you expect resizing to be different from scaling? the first code fragment works if you a) use the size property (frame is readonly) and b) use CGSizeMake. Finally, you could just modify (scale) the CGPath

Comment: resizeToWidth or any resize only works with SKSpriteNode, not with SKShapeNode

Answer (score 9):

The action, `resizeToWidth`, can be called by an SKSpriteNode.

You can call the action, 
`scaleTo`
, with SKShapeNode.

Answer (score -3):

Change it to a var:

```
var shapeNodeName = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSizeMake(100,100))

// change to new size - shape will now be 150 x 150
shapeNodeName = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSizeMake(150,150))
```

Comment: This method destroy with another initliazation all the node children appended to this node.