# Resize SKShapeNode frame, or alternative

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

This issue is tied with this: [Set SKShapeNode frame to calculateAccumutedFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477936/set-skshapenode-frame-to-calculateaccumutedframe)

Is there a way to resize an SKShapeNode's frame. I do not want to scale it, (suggested here: [Resizing a SKShapeNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931376/resizing-a-skshapenode)). Using whatever scale function makes its contents shrink and resize aswell (the line width of 200x200 is way different than 50x50)

I need to take a frame and set it to a specific size. For example this:

```
shape.frame = CGRect(...)
```

Can't do that since frame is get-only. I attempted to override calculateAccumulatedFrame but that does nothing (see top link).

Can someone please suggest an alternative to the same functionality of SKShapeNode that is not halfway built... Or a way to actually change the frame. The basic functionality I need is to create an arc (seen in pictures of link on top) and have that in some sort of SKNode so I can resize, shrink it, etc. the same as you can do with SKSpriteNode

Comment: What both current answers fail to point out is that you can replace the CGPath used for an SKShapeNode. This gives you a sort of scaling. Nightmare, but possible. There is no simple way to solve this problem. You will need to "fake it till you make it".

Comment: SKShapeNode is a half baked idea. It's not proper drawing. It's the kind of thing that happens when something isn't designed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SKShapeNode` is a [node](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skshapenode) based on the Core Graphics path (CGPath).

So there is no direct method of resizings different from scaling as you want.
If you use a `SKSpriteNode` for example you have actions like `resizeByWidth` or `resizeToWidth`.

But about node like shapes you should think to him as you must resize a `CGPath` or `UIBezierPath` using method [like](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibezierpath/1624340-apply) :

```
apply(_ transform: CGAffineTransform)
```

or directly by rebuild your path as for example:

```
let π:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI)
let startAngle: CGFloat = 3 * π / 4
let endAngle: CGFloat = π / 4
myShape.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint.zero, radius: 33.5, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true).cgPath
```

Comment: This helps explain some things thanks. I cannot use SKSpriteNode however because I need to edit the lineWidth and when I convert shape to texture to sprite I will have no way to modify the line width. Maybe I can rebuild the path... but do you know a way I can animate the path being rebuilt? For example I have one that is 200 radius, if I want to make the same one with 20 radius can I have it look like an animation of one shrinking?

Comment: You could build various paths (like a cycle) until you reach your radius (intermediate path) by fadeIn  and fadeOut (and remove) the oldest, but I don't know how could be the final result, but you could try this way.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend making an SKSpriteNode out of your SKShapeNode because SKShapeNode is buggy.

```
let node = SKNode()
node.addChild(shapeNode) //we do this because of the bugs with SKShapeNode
let texture = view.textureFromNode(node, crop:node.calculateAccumulatedFrame)

let spriteNode = SKSpriteNode(texture:texture)
```

Optionally, I would look up ways to save this texture to disk, so that you do not have to render the shape every time.

Comment: Why would you down vote this answer?  It has been 2 1/2 years and the bugs still exist on it. This is a great way to save a lot of resources and the original post literally wanted his SKShapeNode to be a SKSpriteNode lol.  Even his comment to Alessandro that I have never seen could have been handled by rendering the skshapenode to the new linewidth and saving the new texture